# iOS: In app purchase Alert View/popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I wanted to know how this particular style of iAP can be achieved. So far I have found out that we can't change anything regarding the iAP popups because of its security concerns but then why do my iAP looks plain like a default AlertView while this app has managed to present it in an entirely different way.

[image: PopUp that I want to achieve]

[image: PopUp that is currently viewed through my code.]

The first image is what I would like to achieve.

The second image is what I currently have.

Thanks, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to do anything in particular, the IAPs' popups look different on different iOS versions and also depends on current type of biometric as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting current image because it is an **sandbox mode**, once it is gone to live, it will automatically handle by **storekit** framework. No need to do anything.

Comment: OK I will check but can you please tell me if the deployment target of my app needs to be above 11 for this or not? because currently Im on 9.0. Thanks @karthikeyan

Comment: You can deploy it and depends upon your requirement, but you should read more about documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase

Comment: When your working with subscription, there might be some changes from iOS 11.2